# Setting the user environment variables in bash_profile

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to set the user environment variables in home directory in bash_profile. But in home directory,
1)on running ls -l|grep bash_profile,no file is shown
2)For every session, I have to run source ~/.bash_profile to get the environment variables.What is the   other way round to get the variables without running the source command every time.
Please suggest the solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "every session"? Each time you login and start a new SSH session?

Comment: Note that `ls -l` will not show hidden (dot) files - you'd need to add `-a` or `-A`

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may want to use `~/.profile` for the purpose instead of `~/.bash_profile`. Suggested reading on the topic [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).

Answer (score 0):

Include that `source` command into `.bashrc` to run it automatically when opening a terminal. You only see a hidden file, i.e. a file of which the name starts with a dot, in the output of `ls` if you use the `-a` option.